# How we can use XMLHttpRequest function handler in case of wrong resource request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, xmlhttprequest

In angular js when we provide the wrong url in $http.get('').then(onpass,onfail) method we just get the error message it would not show any error message in console.

example

```
$http.get('path').then(onpass, onerror);

var onpass = function(request){$scope.data = request.data };
var onerror = function(request){$scope.error= "error" };
```

Just wanted to know how we can use the same functionality XMLHttpRequest. It would be great if you provide me just one example. I use the same

```
xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open('POST', service + url, false);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhttp.setRequestHeader("APIKey", apiKey);
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        var data = xhttp.responseText;
       // console.log(data);
    }
}
var payload = "{'xyz':{'abc':'" + test+ "', 'test':'" + test+ "'}}";
xhttp.send(payload);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You just check for other combinations of readyState and status (with 0/something generally being a security issue and 4/something being [all sorts of different things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)).